# faster alternative to convert pandas df to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe wih 2 columns , into a dictionary such that the values of one column are the keys, and the values of the other column are the values of the dictionary. If the keys happen to be repeating (which they are), I want the values of the same key to be appended in a list.

So far I did the following , but this takes a very long time if I want to convert a 100K plus records to a dictionary.

```
     A          B
1   ab        kate
2   ab        drew
3   ab        mike
4   ab        eric
5   cd        bobby
6   cd        kyle
7   ab        alex
8   ab        michelle
9   cd        heather

fdict = dict()
for d, d2 in zip(t.A, t.B):
    fdict.setdefault(d, list()).append(d2)
```

Please help me understand how I can do this faster using python.

Thanks !

Comment: How long is "very long"?

Comment: It takes a split second on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think `df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')` this oneliner would serve your purpose and faster.